# Find different textbox values from same class div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs with `class = "deleteDiv1"`, there are two textbox in each div.

I want to loop through all `deleteDiv1` and find `textbox` values in each div.

```
<div class="row deleteDiv1">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="1" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="5" placeholder="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="1#5"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row deleteDiv1">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="3" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="8" placeholder="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="3#8"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

    .... so on
```

What I am trying to do is,

```
if ($('.deleteDiv1').length > 0) {
    $('.deleteDiv1').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(obj).children("input[type=number]").each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
}
```

But this is not working. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` instead of `children()`. `children()` only looks at the immediate children of the node, while `find()` traverses the entire `DOM` until it finds the element you need:

```js
$('.deleteDiv1').each(function(i, obj) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find("input[type=number]").each(function() {
    var textBoxValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(textBoxValue);
    $this.find('.values').append(textBoxValue);
  });
});
```

```css
.values{
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row deleteDiv1">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="1" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="5" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="1#5"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class='values'></div>
</div>

<div class="row deleteDiv1">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="3" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="8" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="3#8"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class='values'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I get both textbox values at once in a div

Comment: @JohnyBravo, there are 4 textboxes. But yes, you can get those in a div.  You want the whole 4 in a div?

Comment: I mean there are two textbox in each "deleteDiv1" class. So when looping on "deleteDiv1", can I get that textbox pair values

Comment: @JohnyBravo, see my updated answer. I've added a `div` with class `values` in each of the `deleteDiv1` elements and appended the values to those elements.

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
if ($('.deleteDiv1').length > 0)
         {
             $('.deleteDiv1').each(function (i, obj) {
                 $(this).find("input[type=number]").each(function () {
                     alert($(this).val());
                 });

             });
         }
```

I hope this will help to solve your problem.

**EDIT**

This is best example for difference between [children and find](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-find-and-children-in-jquery/) so far.

Comment: Need to find both textbox values in a div, so  $('.deleteDiv1').each(function (i, obj) { --here can I get both textbox values in this div at once without looping "input[type=number]"}

Comment: var arr = $.map($(this).find("input[type=number]"),function(v){
 return v;
}); try this

Answer (score 0):

You could use one `each()` with the selector `.deleteDiv1 input[type=number]`, so no need for `.children()` and second `each()` :

```
$('.deleteDiv1 input[type=number]').each(function (i, v) {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.deleteDiv1 input[type=number]').each(function (i, v) {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row deleteDiv1"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd"><label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label><div class="col-lg-7"><input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="1" class="form-control" placeholder="0"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd"><label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label><div class="col-lg-7"><input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="5" placeholder="0"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="1#5"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a></div></div>

<div class="row deleteDiv1"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd"><label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label><div class="col-lg-7"><input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="3" class="form-control" placeholder="0"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd"><label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label><div class="col-lg-7"><input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="8" placeholder="0"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="3#8"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a></div></div>
```

Comment: Have you checked that @JohnyBravo ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.deleteDiv1').each(function(i, obj) {
  $('input[type=number]', obj).each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row deleteDiv1">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="1" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="5" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="1#5"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row deleteDiv1">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">From</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" value="3" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group form-group-xs spdfd">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-5">To</label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" value="8" placeholder="0">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 pl-5"><a class="text-warning delete-btn" id="3#8"><i class="icon-minus2"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try this way